# Popup ads being display on webpage while running from Xampp

Tags: popup, xampp

I am using XAMPP version 3.2.1.

Recently I have noticed whenever i run my website from local host, some strange pop up ads are display on the right corner. This is case only for the pages run from xampp directory and not for online websites. I tried uninstalling few programs as well as re-installed chrome. I check my entire directory for any such virus but the problem is still there.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This could be adware, although it's a slim possibility. Have you tried this procedure with another computer? Do you have ads on your website?

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes to dat could be

1. Addons installed in the browser so check ur browser addon manager an uninstall any plugin u don't remember installing urself.
2. Check ur code may be inadvertently  u ve  dropped an ads code dat does that. So please review ur code

Comment: Please use correct english when replying to answers. This is not a mobile phone.